# What is the working of this thread in C++/CX?

Tags: c++-cx

Here is the code:

```
//statement 1
auto task1 = ref new WorkItemHandler([&](IAsyncAction^ task2)
{
    //statement 2
    if (task2->Status == AsyncStatus::Canceled)
    {
            //statement 3
    }
    Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::High,    //statement A
            ref new DispatchedHandler(
            [=]()
    {
            //statement 4                                  
    }));
    }
);
//statement 5
IAsyncAction ^ thread = Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync(task2);  //statement B
//statement 6
```

I want to know the working of this thread.

In what order and when are the statements labelled from 1-6 executed?

And in the lambda expression, from where does the task2 parameter receive value (above statement 2)?

What do the statements labelled A and B do? What is the difference between them?

Comment: please anybody answer

Comment: does nobody know about this! weird!

Comment: Why is nobody answering?

Answer (score 2):

In your method's current implementation, statement 1 will run first.  This is basically the creation of a new object, WorkItemHandler, which is encapsulating the lambda containing statements 2, 3, 4, and A.

However, nothing in the code shown will cause this lambda to be executed, so at no point will statements 2, 3, 4, or A execute.

The next statement that will execute is 5, which will schedule task2 (whose definition I can't see) to run on a threadpool thread.  Either statement 6 or task2 will be executed next, as these are happening on different threads this may occur asynchronously.

Statement A is causing the created DispatchedHandler (which contains a lambda encapsulating statement 4) to run on the STA (UI) thread.  This is one way to marshal a call back to the UI thread, which is necessary if statement 4 will modify some UI or call methods on a UI-bound class.  Failing to marshal back to the UI thread can result in WrongThreadException's.

Statement B causes task2 to run on a ThreadPool thread.  Unlike the UI thread, this is an arbitrary worker thread that will be in the multithreaded apartment (MTA). This is suitable for situations where you do not need to access or modify UI (e.g. performing compute-intensive processing).